# Adding days to given date jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add some days into a given date and below are my codes:
Example: Given date = 2015/11/27 11:00, number of days = 2
My result should be 2015/11/29 11:00..

```
function setEndDate(date) {
    var duration = $("#duration").val();
    var dValue = parseInt($("#showDValue").val()) * 7;

    if (duration == "Week(s)") {
         date.setDate(date.getDate() + dValue);
    }
}
```

But i m getting error of this :

```
TypeError: date.getDate is not a function
```

Any solution?? Please help...

Comment: `date=new Date(date)`

Comment: The value which is passed to `setEndDate` is not a `Date` object.

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate for `date object` object before `getDate`.

```js
function setEndDate(date) {
  var dateObj;
  if (date instanceof Date) {
    dateObj = date;
  } else {
    dateObj = Date.parse(date);
    if (dateObj == NaN) {
      throw "Pass a valid date string or object !"
    }
  }
  var duration = $("#duration").val();
  var dValue = parseInt($("#showDValue").val()) * 7;

  if (duration == "Week(s)") {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + dValue);
  }
 $("#result").append(date.toString());
}

setEndDate(new Date());

setEndDate("10-Dec-2015");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="duration" type="number"></input>

<input id="showDValue" type="number"></input>
<div id="result"></div>
```